# Встроенные покупки. Достаточно ли для аппрува в Apple?

Tags: appstore, ios, apple, unity3d

Здравствуйте. Делаю встроенные покупки в Unity с помощью плагина `Prime31 StoreKit`. 
Сейчас у меня так: одна кнопка в меню отвечает и за Restore и за Purchase. То есть при нажатии на кнопку сначала вызывается функция Restore, и далее если не было ничего восстановлено, то, соответственно, инициирую покупку. Покупка `Non-consumable`.

Я думал, что все норм. Но потом открыл StoreKitGuide. И такого прочитал, что ужаснулся, и начало казаться, что нужно еще много чего сделать. Например, эта строчка:

> If you need to support versions of iOS
> earlier than iOS7 , wherethe app
> receipti sn’t available, restore
> completed transactions instead

Что делать с этим app `receipt`? Или есть такая штука, как rebuy, похожая на Restore. Нужно ли ее поддерживать? То есть если игрок нажал на кнопку купить, а игра куплена, то запускать ли рестор или запускать ребай (в смысле обычную покупку)?

Очень много таких моментов непонятных. Кто уже проходил аппрув в Apple со встроенными покупами, может, сможет объяснить, что должно поддерживаться приложением точно для успеха?

Заранее спасибо. )

Answer (score 1):

Просто делаешь покупку еще раз, если у тебя нет данных в приложении, что это уже куплено. Стор сам предупредит пользователя, что он уже купил это, а тебе просто придет коллбэк типа покупка прошла.

Comment: это вроде и называется rebuy. А куда тогда Restore запихнуть?